# How to Implement Singleton (or shared resources) in Azure .Net 5 Isolated Functions?

Tags: azure, dependency-injection, azure-functions, singleton, .net-5

I'm trying to configure my .Net 5 Azure Function (Isolated) to share a resource via singleton or DI, but in this article under "Dependency Injection":
https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/azure-functions/dotnet-isolated-process-guide

I'm getting an error implementing AddSingleton.

**Error:** 'IServiceCollection' does not contain a definition for 'AddSingleton'

**Microsoft snippet:**

```
.ConfigureServices(s =>
{
    s.AddSingleton<IHttpResponderService, DefaultHttpResponderService>();
})
```

**My interpretation:**

```
public static void Main()
{
    var host = new HostBuilder()
        .ConfigureFunctionsWorkerDefaults()
        .ConfigureServices(s =>
            {
                s.AddSingleton<IHttpResponderService, DefaultHttpResponderService>();
            })
        .Build();

    host.Run();
}
```

Microsoft states that you don't need a Startup class for DI, but there is little doco as this has just been released (2021-03-21).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This code is available at github:

https://github.com/Azure/azure-functions-dotnet-worker-preview/blob/main/FunctionApp/Program.cs

Under known issues it states:

> Deployment to Azure is currently limited to Windows plans. Note that
> some optimizations are not in place in the consumption plan and you
> may experience longer cold starts.

Are you running under a Linux app service plan?

Comment: I was missing a dependency: using Microsoft.Extensions.DependencyInjection; And no, I'm currently running under a Windows service plan.